# Is saying 'I do a job' grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs

My sister wanted to convey the idea that she works somewhere and she used this sentence which I found quite odd. I tried looking for similar sentences but only found sentences like, 'she does odd jobs' which sounds perfectly fine. But saying 'I do a job' sounds very wrong grammatically and otherwise.

Comment: Iff you are trying to convey the idea that you are employed, then: **I have a job** is usually said. You should use the extra space to explain your thinking behind your question so the answerers can advise you appropriately.

Comment: -1 This is not a good question. It needs details. Please add the context or purpose for such a statement.

Comment: In English, *do* can refer to any activity. Whether native speakers would say *I do {something}* depends on the context.

Comment: Instead of filling the space with nonsense, try telling us more about what you are trying to say. Our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post might help.

Comment: You are right. It's not correct. We would say, "I have a job" to mean that we work somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a job

means *I am employed* or *I work.*

Answer (score 1):

I do a job

The sentence isn't ungrammatical, but the use of the verb "do" in the context is far less common. You usually say:

I have a job.

I am working or I work.

I am employed.

I am in a job (though less common).

In BrE, you can also say:

I am in work.

Answer (score 0):

"I do paint houses" is a valid statement.

Usually people will say "I paint houses".

The exact sentence you said is valid English.  (However, since most people do a job of some sort, the sentence seems to have little point, just like "I breathe" is usually something that people safely assume.)

Answer (score 0):

In what context would you use this phrase? Variations of the phrase that would be used more often are "I did a job [where I...]" as in past tense.

If you're talking about being employed, try using "My job is..." or a longer version like "I work at (somewhere, e.g. Intel) where I (job e.g. build computers)."

Answer (score 0):

I do a job.
The sentence is grammatical.

Incorrec:With the right tools, I could make the job in five minutes.
Correct: With the right tools, I could do the job in five minutes.

Do a job (NOT make ):

'There are lots of jobs to do when we get home.' (= pieces of work) 'There's no need to thank me. I was just doing my job.' (= what I do to earn a living)

Reference :Longman Dictionary of Common Errors.

Comment: @I don't know who I am, The OP means his permanent job for which he gets paid regularly. (Call me at 03332255829 Aslam).